# Firebase Storage - Different projects load images with different speeds

Tags: flutter, firebase, performance, firebase-storage

I have multiple projects using Google Firebase and am using Firebase Storage to store my images and load them on mobile devices. The mobile app is developed on Flutter.

The marketplace app project loads images pretty quick, while the other app is very slow with the loads [nearly 5 seconds :(]

Below are the links to pics from each project. First one, being 900+kb loads pretty quick, but second one being 77kb takes much longer. What I see is the webpage itself takes so much time to load when open in the browser. At first I thought it must be the loading and caching in the app but now since it behaves differently on the browser to load, I am confused.

I am not sure maybe I am overlooking at some settings. Please help :)

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/revivemarketplace-e61ec.appspot.com/o/03523bc0-cb82-11eb-a754-47c8b7348079?alt=media&token=ec7d02d5-7f6b-4493-9c99-6d2e9ac53da2

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/diaeh/o/resized1000%2F00000apexels-christina-morillo-1181244_1000x1000.jpg?alt=media&token=b698c7ae-38ab-41ac-8761-bc6f4f18d98a

Answer (score 0):

you can try this formula

Reupload your pic to firebase and set new link to your app of image

Comment: Thank you! The app is dynamic and there are many images added everyday. The same happens to all of them. Load time is too much. Im just wondering why it takes too much time when opening on the browser as well? I am wondering if it is something related to resource allocation? 

Here is another one: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/diaeh/o/resized1000%2F048d4050-f76b-11ec-9967-91579998db00_1000x1000?alt=media&token=6e474942-8feb-45ab-9b41-e04222563c7a

Comment: You are right because Firebase did not build for lots of data. for handle lots of data i recommend  to use any mysql database instead of it. if you still want to going with firebase then i have one idea.

Comment: there is idea:-When user upload some image from application. at that time first of all image must be compressed and then after upload into the firebase

Comment: I have added a cloud function that compresses the images. The files before compression are 3MB + but after compression comes to less than 500KB mostly. Even after compression it is slow loading.

Comment: Did you set timeout property ? In your flutter app with image widget